# リストが表示されない原因を教えてください。

Tags: python, python3

```
fruit=["apple","orange","pear"]
fruit
```

独学で一から勉強しているのですが、本の通り上記のコードを実行しても、対話シェルに何も表示されません。
こんな基本的なことで申し訳ありませんが、何を直せばいいか教えてください。
使用言語はPythonでVer3.6.5になります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

コメントありがとうございます。

Windowsでやってます。Python3.6.5 shell (IDLE)を開いて、`file ⇒ new file`で、出てくるテキストエディタに上記コードを入力し`RUN`という流れです。シェルには`>>>`の後になにも表示されない状態です。

これで伝わりますでしょうか？わからないことが多くて申し訳ありません。お願いいたします。

Comment: 「対話シェル」と書かれていますが、実行OS(Windows, Linux)やコードを打つまでに行った手順等、できるだけ詳しく書いてみてください(質問は後からでも「編集」できます)。

Comment: 恐らく「対話シェル」を起動しただけでpythonのインタプリタを起動していないんじゃないかなぁという気がします。

Answer (score 1):

Python IDLE から **プログラムファイルを** 実行した場合、単に変数を評価させただけではインタプリタに値が表示されません。

より細かく説明すると、

```
fruit = ["apple", "orange", "pear"]
fruit
```

の 2 行目は `fruit` という変数を評価させただけであり、Python のプログラムとしては「`fruit` の内容を出力せよ」という意味は **持ちません**。ただしインタプリタの上でプログラムを 1 行ずつ打ち込んだ場合、インタプリタの機能として `fruit` が評価された結果の値が出力されます。以下は私の環境においてインタプリタの上で動かしてみた結果です。質問者さんの環境でも、ファイルを実行する代わりにインタプリタへ 1 行ずつ打ち込むと同じ結果になるはずです。

```
>>> fruit = ["apple", "orange", "pear"]
>>> fruit
['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
>>>
```

プログラムとして出力させたい場合、`print` 関数を使います。プログラムファイルを以下のように編集し、Python IDLE でファイルを実行した場合、ちゃんと `fruit` の内容が表示されるはずです。

```
fruit = ["apple", "orange", "pear"]
print(fruit)
```